# Executing SoapUI tests in parallel by Maven

Tags: java, maven, soapui, functional-testing

Does anybody knows if it's possible to execute SoapUI tests in parallel by Maven? I have a lot of soap tests in my project, it would be great to run them in parallel on Jenkins.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html  .Maven 2 or later they say

Answer (score 1):

In your project turn on parallel test execution. Official [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html#2-Test-Execution) is available.

In your Maven, configure the soapui-maven-plugin. Official [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html) is available. Same configuration is for Maven 3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to run SoapUI tests in parallel by Maven. You need to have the Maven 2 or above version of plugin to able to run SoapUI tests in parallel with Maven.

Please add the Maven repository to your project or Settings XML file before doing you parallel execution.